# Configure dynamic stored procedure with ssrs reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have the following SP

CREATE PROCEDURE Studentrocedure
    @Type varchar(50)

```
AS
BEGIN

    If @Type  = 'Student'
    Select * from tblStudent
    Else If  @Type  = 'Fee'
    Select * from tblFee
    End
END
```

The problem I'm having is that when I add a DataSet for a SSRS report, it pulls no fields/columns in the Fields section.

How can I resolve that?

Comment: Split this into two separate sp.

Comment: You are right, but I want to create one procedure to handle 10 type of report. In your case I will create 10 separate procedure.

Comment: Correct - 10 separate sps.

Comment: Right now all of your potential SPs look like a trivial ad-hoc `select *` - not sure if you need any sp at all. Why don't you select from tables/views directly? There is no specific logic in demonstrated piece of code.

Comment: I have mention sample piece of code otherwise in procedure I have 10 to 15 parameter therefor I don't use directly tables/views.

Comment: And parameter list of 10-15 items is absolutely similar for completely different tables like `Student` and `Fee`?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Then what is different in those queries? If they have similar params then they are filtering rows by similar columns. If they have similar columns then they have similar part of queries. Add some real code to your question, it's too abstract right now.

Answer (score 0):

- Syntax error near the `ELSE` part, it should be `ELSE IF`.
- Also no need of the extra `End` in the query
- Instead of `*` explicitly mention the column names

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Studentrocedure
    @Type varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

    IF @Type  = 'Student'
        Select * from tblStudent
    ELSE IF  @Type  = 'Fee' 
        Select * from tblFee
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You really can't resolve this assuming that your select * queries return different result sets. A dataset requires a deterministic set of fields. You can not dynamically determine the fields that will be included in a dataset.

If you are confident that your dynamically selected results will always and forever return the same set of columns regardless of the input given then you can explore using FMTONLY option.

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434827/no-fields-for-dynamic-sql-stored-procedure-in-ssrs-with-set-fmtonly)